# How do you deserialize Transunion XML?

Tags: c#, .net, partial-classes, xsd.exe, xml-deserialization

Here is my attempt, xsd and classes created from xsd.exe

Running my code I get error "There is an error in XML document (1, 2)."  Inner exception {" was not expected."}

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

XML Snippet:

```
 <xml>
  <creditBureau xmlns="http://www.transunion.com/namespace"
                xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <document>response</document>
    <version>2.2</version>
    <transactionControl>
      <userRefNumber>260907</userRefNumber>
      <subscriber>
        <industryCode>P</industryCode>
        <memberCode>04784547</memberCode>
        <inquirySubscriberPrefixCode>1527</inquirySubscriberPrefixCode>
      </subscriber>...
```

XSD Snippet:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:tns="http://www.transunion.com/namespace" 
           attributeFormDefault="unqualified" 
           elementFormDefault="qualified" 
           targetNamespace="http://www.transunion.com/namespace" 
           xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="creditBureau">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="document" type="xs:string" />
        <xs:element name="version" type="xs:decimal" />
        <xs:element name="transactionControl">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
              <xs:element name="userRefNumber" type="xs:unsignedInt" />
              <xs:element name="subscriber">...
```

Class Snippet:

```
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("xsd", "4.0.30319.1")]
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType=true, Namespace="http://www.transunion.com/namespace")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute(Namespace="http://www.transunion.com/namespace", IsNullable=false)]
public partial class creditBureau {
    private string documentField;
    private decimal versionField;
    private creditBureauTransactionControl transactionControlField;
    private creditBureauProduct productField;

    public string document {
        get {
            return this.documentField;
        }
        set {
            this.documentField = value;
        }
    }

    public decimal version {
        get {
            return this.versionField;
        }
        set {
            this.versionField = value;
        }
    }

    public creditBureauTransactionControl transactionControl {
        get {
            return this.transactionControlField;
        }
        set {
            this.transactionControlField = value;
        }
    }

    public creditBureauProduct product {
        get {
            return this.productField;
        }
        set {
            this.productField = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Code Snippet:

```
    FileStream fs = new FileStream("XMLFile1.xml", FileMode.Open);
    XmlSerializer x = new XmlSerializer(typeof(creditBureau));
    creditBureau c = (creditBureau)x.Deserialize(fs);
```

Comment: I know this is an old post, but if you happen to see this Bleeped, where did you find an XSD for TransUnion's Net Access system? I've searched their site and even called their service department and come up empty. Can you point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the XML you posted is exactly what you receive, the error occurs because the XML document is incorrect:

```
<xml>
```

Is not a valid XML declaration tag, it should be something like that:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

Comment: Thank you so much!  I could not see the forest through the trees.